# AWS - Node app won't connect to running mongo instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

I installed mongo on my elastic beanstalk node.js app and started the mongo daemon process. I'm not quite sure how to connect to the database though. On my local node app, I'm able to connect with these credentials:

```
module.exports = {
  'url' : 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test'
}
```

I'm assuming that it doesn't connect because I need a user, password, and to create a database to connect to, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that on the remote database. I'm also finding resources on setting mongo up on t1.micro to be very scarce, so there's not much help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that I had to start up the mongo processes myself. Run `mongod`.